# numpy: opposite of nonzero (get indices of zero elements)

Tags: python, numpy

[`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) is useful for getting indices of nonzero elements. It returns a tuple of arrays, each of which contains the indices of nonzero elements for a particular axis.

Is there an equivalent but for **zero** element instead?

Meaning that for the given numpy array

```py
x = [[1, 2, 0],
     [8, 0, 2],
     [0, 0, 1]]
```

I could get the indices as follows

```py
ax0_zero_idxs, ax1_zero_idxs = numpy.zero(x)
```

where

```
ax0_zero_idxs = [0, 1, 2, 2]
ax1_zero_idxs = [2, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Just use `x==0` there with `np.nonzero`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `x == 0` generates a *bool* array with each element
answering the question: Is corresponding element of *x* equal to *0*?

So you can apply *np.nonzero* to just this array:

```
result np.nonzero(x == 0)
```

Try yourself.

The same way you can get indices of elements meeting any other condition.

Comment: thanks, that works! for the record, i had to do `np.nonzero(~(x != 0))` because `x` was as sparse matrix and apparently it's much faster with sparse matrices to do `!= 0` rather than `== 0` (warning raised by scipy)